# Symfony2 extend ACL with additional Permissions

Tags: php, symfony

I want to implement the Symfony2 ACL into my project. The basic permissions (VIEW, EDIT...) are however not sufficient for me. I would need at least two additional permissions, namely COPY and REVIEW.

After some digging around, I found that I will mostly likely have to overwrite/extend `Symfony/Component/Security/Acl/Permission/BasicPermissionMap.php` and `Symfony/Component/Security/Acl/Permission/MaskBuilder.php`.

In `Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/security_acl.xml` I found a line that refers to the permission map:

```
<parameter key="security.acl.permission.map.class">Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Permission\BasicPermissionMap</parameter>
```

I tried overwriting this in `app/config/config.yml`, but that didn't work (I got an error that the permission config key was unknown, or something like that).

I've been looking at the services as well, by using `app/console container:debug`, but I couldn't find any relevant service to overwrite there either.

Could someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: I think the COPY and REVIEW permissions are better as roles. I'm trying to think of what actions aren't covered by the standard ACL that would be covered by this, but can't see any. COPY ~= View. As a role any user that can view an object can create a new copy of it. REVIEW is maybe a composition of VIEW & DELETE?

Comment: How did you try to overwrite the parameter? What's the exact error?

Comment: I have managed to find a way to do it and will post an answer soon. COPY and REVIEW are not possible as roles as Object OWNERs are able to say "this project can be copied by this user, this one can be reviewed, this one can be viewed and this one can be editted".

Comment: I'd be quite interested in your solution, @Bram. :)

Comment: @MichaelB I have added my answer. I would however now recommend not using the ACL. We're looking into getting rid of it. I would suggest implementing custom voters: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html

Comment: @Bram Thanks! I actually found your gist as well. However, would you mind telling me why you're considering usind voters instead? I'm creating a SaaS application where one company can have multiple "sub companies" and a user can have permissions to do certain things (e.g. "create article") **per sub company**. There will be several (like 8-10) of these kinds of custom permissions, and I'm not sure how I would use voters for that, whereas I think an ACL (ACE: "User A has permission 'create article' for sub company X") would work fine. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @MichaelB Mostly because there's not a lot of people using it. Even Fabien Potencier has publicly said he doesn't use the ACL, but uses custom voters. You will probably somewhere in your database store the relations anyway. It would be easier to implement a voter that will allow you more flexibility in the future. For example, we have a "COPY" permission. It worked fine, but now I need to further restrict it to "ONLY COPY IF...", which is not easily possible with the ACL, but it is with custom voters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I solved it (this has become easier in Symfony 2.3 after I submitted a PR):

Extend the existing MaskBuilder with your own masks:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Acl\Permission;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Permission\MaskBuilder as BaseMaskBuilder;

class MaskBuilder extends BaseMaskBuilder
{
    const MASK_COPY         = 256;        // 1 << 8
    const MASK_REVIEW       = 512;        // 1 << 9

    const CODE_COPY         = 'X';
    const CODE_REVIEW       = 'R';
}
```

Extend the existing PermissionMap (you used to have to completely override it, as everything was set to private).

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Acl\Permission;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Permission\BasicPermissionMap;

class PermissionMap extends BasicPermissionMap
{
    const PERMISSION_COPY        = 'COPY';
    const PERMISSION_REVIEW      = 'REVIEW';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // This basically says "If you have VIEW, REVIEW, EDIT..., OWNER, 
        // you have VIEW".
        $this->map[self::PERMISSION_VIEW] = array(
            MaskBuilder::MASK_VIEW,
            MaskBuilder::MASK_REVIEW,
            MaskBuilder::MASK_EDIT,
            MaskBuilder::MASK_COPY,
            MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
            MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
            MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
        );
        $this->map[self::PERMISSION_COPY] = array(
            MaskBuilder::MASK_COPY,
            MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
            MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
            MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
        );
        $this->map[self::PERMISSION_REVIEW] = array(
            MaskBuilder::MASK_REVIEW,
            MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
            MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
            MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
        );
    }
}
```

Don't ask me why you have to include the same permission.

Lastly, you need to tell Symfony to use your PermissionMap in `config.yml`:

```
parameters:
    security.acl.permission.map.class: Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Acl\Permission\PermissionMap
```

That did it for me.